# htaccess redirect to a parent folder

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

I want to htaccess to redirect to parent folder.

For ex:

- localhost/**(unknown directory path)**/sample/a.html

should be redirected to

- localhost/**(unknown directory path)**/a.html

I added following htaccess file in sample folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Sample/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

this was redirected to localhost/a.html I want to redirect to localhost/**(unknown directory path)**/a.html.

 Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this `.htaccess`in your `sample` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am not sure if it is possible to use a relative link. But I do not have the opportunity to test here

You can also use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/sample(/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=301,L]
```